# Were "pachim ketanim" particularly desirable utensils?

Tags: vayishlach, bava-kamma, utensil, zav-zava

Were "pachim ketanim - small vessels" particularly desirable in the time when we were careful for tumah and taharah as the Gemara [Bava Kamma (25b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.25b.5?lang=bi) says they are impervious to tumah of a zav? (Is that another reason why Yaakov Avinu returned for the "pachim ketanim" in [Bereishis 32:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.32.25.1?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)?)

Comment: Y Avenue was a brave man, idk if I would have went back for my patchouli oil, hot sauce and gold scraps

Comment: The point is that they were not so valuable, and still Yaakov returned for them, to show that tzaddikim value their possessions.

Comment: https://www.orhamelech.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%97-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A4-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%91%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D-%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A9-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95.pdf